# I would like to have Printing services added to the Debian apache PHP installation

Tags: php, apache, printing, debian

I have a debian Server Running Apache 2 and it runs PHP I would like to load printing services. In Windows Wamp setup you are able to load Printer.dll via the extension=php_printer.dll in the PHP.ini file in windows But if I look in the phpinfo() of the window system i see a printer heading, If i look at phpinfo() on the debian linux installation I do not see a printer section. How do I get a printer.so file for my version of debian apache and php.

Comment: This should be posted on http://serverfault.com/ for a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @Bun No, it shouldn't.

Comment: @MichaelHampton `[...]Answers to every question about professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration.` This question seemed like a server administration question, but you may be right... It doesn't fit the description perfectly...

Comment: @Bun "How to print from PHP on Linux" is a _programming_ question, though not a very good one in its present state. This question suffers from the XY problem.